# Annotation for Any class?

Tags: kotlin

```
annotation class MyClass(
    val value : Class
)
```

syntax error for class

> One type argument expected for class Class<T: Any!>

How to fix this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with annotation. The error message explains itself, [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) type is generic which cannot be use without specifying the type. It is not clear what you want to do so cannot recommend a "fix" for you.

Comment: I want to be able to create an annotation that i can input the Class (eg `MyOtherClass`) into the annotation like this: `@MyClass(MyOtherClass)`. Just need the annotation to store the Class Object.

Comment: It still looks like you probably want a [type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html) rather than an [annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html).

Answer (score 0):

From the official kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#instantiation)

> If you need to specify a class as an argument of an annotation, use a
> Kotlin class (KClass). The Kotlin compiler will automatically convert
> it to a Java class, so that the Java code can access the annotations
> and arguments normally.

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

annotation class MyClass(
    val value : KClass<*>
)
```